# How to active link by jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Here is my navigation code, I am trying to active it by jquery But I need a small solution.

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
               <li class="active" id="dashboard">
                 <a href="admin/users/dashboard">Dashboard</a>                    
               </li>
               <li id="clients">
                 <a href="admin/users/clients">Clients</a>                    
               </li>
            </ul>
 </nav>
```

I can active link by using `onclick` event. Per page If I right

```
$('#deshboard').click(function(){
   $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

It's working but need to write lots of code. Have there any easy solution ?

Comment: So, after adding this `active` class, it will navigate to another page which means that you will loose any client-side changes. Right?

Comment: If I navigate to another page I need to write again active code for active page. For example if I go clients page. I need to wright $('#clients').click(function(){.......   I need actually a small solution as like if this link active in url then active this link.

Comment: I mean, if you always return such HTML code as you have shown, then you will always have `dashboard` as `active` item. Even if you apply such script, when you click `clients`, it will become `active` for a second, then a page will reload and `dashboard` will become active again while you are at `clients` page. You need to set it server-side.

Comment: yes you are right. I want active link after click it may according to url.

Answer (score 2):

simply do the following:

Just use a single class for all the links, for example "common_class" and then do the following,

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
               <li class="active common_class">
                 <a href="admin/users/dashboard">Dashboard</a>                    
               </li>
               <li class="common_class">
                 <a href="admin/users/clients">Clients</a>                    
               </li>
            </ul>
 </nav>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('.common_class').click(function(){
   $('.common_class').removeClass('active');   // it remove all the active links
   $(this).addClass('active');    // it adds active class to the current link you have opened
})
```

this would save a lot of code of yours, and it's easy to understand.

**NOTE: Add this jquery in the header file, which must be same for all the pages.**

go with it

Comment: @SatuSultana i am agree Insomania's Answer, smart and simple ;)

Comment: It's not working after load page. I think it should be URL base change.

Comment: you must use the same header file for both of the pages, if header file is not created then call the above jquery function on both of the files,

Answer (score 0):

Use common class in `UL` tag

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                     <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav  common_class ">
                       <li class="active" id="dashboard">
                         <a href="admin/users/dashboard">Dashboard</a>                    
                       </li>
                       <li id="clients">
                         <a href="admin/users/clients">Clients</a>                    
                       </li>
                    </ul>
         </nav>
```

And JS will be:

```
$('.common_class li').click(function(){
   $('.common_class li').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
})
```